# PHPCassa - Can't insert when using uuid timestamp as key

Tags: php, cassandra, uuid, phpcassa

I'm trying to store data into cassandra with it being ordered by time. Having trouble using the TimeUUIDType as the key.

I get the following error with phpcassa...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cassandra_InvalidRequestException' 
with message 'TimeUUID   should be 16 or 0 bytes (6)'
```

This occurs when calling the insert method...

```
$pool = new ConnectionPool("Keyspace1", array("localhost:9160"));
$column_family = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'users');
$column_family->insert(CassandraUtil::uuid1(), array('name' => 'value'));
```

I created a test table using cassandra-cli with the following command...

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY users WITH comparator = TimeUUIDType;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comparator` applies to column names, not row keys.  If you want the row keys to be TimeUUIDs, you should set `key_validation_class` instead.

You're getting this exception because Cassandra is expecting a TimeUUID for the column name, but you're passing a normal string.